# What are good alternatives to Mac Address Book for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, address-book

I used Address Book on Mac and I really liked the software. It's simple, easy and it has all the things I needed in an address book. Now, I recently switched to Windows 7 and I am looking for a software which works like Address Book. Light weight with Speed. Even, a Website or a Cloud App which syncs contacts from my system to the cloud is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Vista [contacts are built-in](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Managing-your-contacts), if you have MS Office you might also want to consider MS Outlook.

Another alternative is [Free Address Book](http://addressbook.gassoftwares.com/).

> Free Address Book is an address book wherewith you can note the addresses, phone numbers, mobile, fax, company name, country, city, website address and email addresses of your contacts and partners.
>
> You can easy print list of contacts and details of selected contact.
>   Phone Book is absolutely free!
>
> Organize your contacts easy and fast!

Comment: I checked out Free Address Book and it looks like a good option. However, is there someway where I can transfer Mac Address Book contacts to Free Address book?

Comment: @Ctroy: Seems it only allows to import CSV files for now. I suppose Mac exports iCard files so I don't think you can, I'm sorry...

Answer (score 0):

[Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/).

Plus Android and addressbook nirvana arrives regardless of computing platform.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use for email?

Thunderbird and the Contacts extension work for me.  And I access my contacts on my phone as well with Google.